# Improving the performance of a nested for loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I developed a web server in node.js and a web page (see Picture) hosted on this web server. The web server is embedded in the raspberry pi and I used a HAT with a D/A converter in order to generate voltages to an external circuit.

[image: Webpage section]

In the web page can be selected, if the user wants to use one channel or two channel of the DAC. Likewise, the parameters for the ramp generation from 0.0 to 5.0 V (incremental) or 5.0 V to 0.0 V (decremental). These settings are stored as a string in a vector which is passed to the web server using socket.io.

For the specific case of selecting two channels, the program executes a nested loop like the shown below. Where:

```
//i= Start Value (DAC0); val_max=Final value (DAC0); forSign="<=" or ">=" ;
//j= Start Value (DAC1); val_max=Final value (DAC1);
//incr = i='i+step' or i='i-step' --> step= Step Value (DAC0)
//incr1 = i='i+step' or i='i-step' --> step= Step Value (DAC1)

        for(i; eval(i+forSign+val_max); i=eval(incr)){

            for(j; eval(j+forSign+val_max1); j=eval(incr1)){

             execSync(com_dac.replace(/dac0/g,j).replace(/dac1/g,i));
                spawnSync("sudo",['./ads1256_test', 'adc.txt']);
                ADC_read = fs.readFileSync("adc.txt").toString()

            }
}
```

However, the performance of the for loop is not the best. Sometimes it is executed, but sometimes not. There is any suggestion to improve passing the parameters to the for loop? Taking into an account that ***i*** and ***j*** are values, while ***step***, ***val_max(1)*** and ***forSign*** are string variables. I would appreciate any feedback :)

Comment: what should the code do?

Comment: I would not use eval within the for loop. That is going is going to kill performance. The eval function is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.

Comment: Please, don't use eval...

Comment: I don't think this is because of `eval`. Nothing bad to use it this way. It seems for me, the main performance issues might be in `Sync` commands you're running inside the cycles. You don't provide any information about `ads1256_test` executable, as well as about `com_dac` value. There might be performance issues with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you used eval()? It should be avoided unless there is a very valid rationale behind the use of it.

First, if you're using eval() for arithmetic expression, JavaScript does this automatically. Needless to use eval().

Second, eval() lacks the performance boost of caching compiled codes that modern JavaScript engine offers. With limited ram such as a Pi, this will prove to be a performance issue.